# Ng-pattern matching with UIMask

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have two simple `inputs` on my form.  I need them to match but since they are phone numbers, I added a `uimask` to them so the user can only enter numbers and it is auto formatted as `(999)-999-9999`.

My issue is that all of my attempts at ensuring the two fields match each other are coming up wrong.  I can never get them to match (from a model perspective) if I am using `uimask`.  If I remove `uimask` from my form then the matching works as expected.

Please review this [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YxLjdo) to see the issue occurring.  Am I missing something?  Or am I simply not allowed to pattern match two fields that use `uimask`?

Here is a shortened example in case the codepen doesn't work.  I am always seeing the error message of `doesnt match` even though the two fields have identical values in them.

```
 <form name="demo" class="container"> 
 <input class="form-control" type="text" 
         id="phone" 
         name="phone" 
         ng-model="x"
         ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" />

 <input class="form-control" type="text" 
         id="phone2" 
         name="phone2" 
         ng-model="y" 
         ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" 
         ng-pattern="(x)"/>

 <div ng-messages="demo.phone2.$error" role="alert">
    <div class="text-danger" ng-message="pattern">doesnt match.</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misunderstanding how [`ng-pattern`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern) works.  `ng-pattern` is a regex validator, which `ui-mask` already addresses to a small extent.  In your example, the second input is literally looking to match the the regex `/^(x)$/`, which would match the literal string `"x"`, not the variable contained there.

If you want to verify that the two inputs match, you'll have to add your own validation.  A simple way of doing this is just adding `ng-change` events to manually manipulate the form element validity with [`$setValidity(validationErrorKey, isValid)`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$setValidity).  I'd personally put this kind of kind in the controller for your form, but these adaptations to the code in your codepen should work.

```
  <input class="form-control" ng-class="{requiredControl:demo.phone.$dirty && demo.phone.$invalid}" type="text" 
         id="phone" 
         name="phone" 
         ng-model="x"
         ng-change="demo.phone2.$setValidity('match', x==y)"
         ng-required="true"
         ui-options="{clearOnBlur:false}" ui-mask-placeholder 
         ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" 
         ui-mask="(999) 999-9999" />    

  <input class="form-control" ng-class="{requiredControl:demo.phone.$dirty && demo.phone.$invalid}" type="text" 
         id="phone2" 
         name="phone2" 
         ng-model="y" 
         ng-required="true"
         ng-change="demo.phone2.$setValidity('match', x==y)"
         ui-options="{clearOnBlur:false}" ui-mask-placeholder 
         ui-mask-placeholder-char="_" 
         ui-mask="(999) 999-9999"/>
```

And then just make sure that you refer the the proper error label in `ng-messages`.  I used a new error labeled `'match'` instead of the built-in `'pattern'` to better communicate what the validation is for.

```
<div ng-messages="demo.phone.$error" role="alert" ng-if="demo.phone.$dirty">
     <div class="text-danger" ng-message="match">doesnt match.</div>
</div>
```

[Branch of your codepen](https://codepen.io/ryanyuyu/pen/gxzQOE)

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you for the help.  I was definitely confusing what `ng-pattern` was doing there :-)

Comment: One follow up question...what is the preferred way to fire off the validity logic from page load?  When I load the page and the fields have data, the error message isn't shown until I change someone in the fields.  I would like the fields to be auto marked as invalid.

Comment: If you need logic to run on page load, I recommend creating an angular controller and doing that kind of setup in the controller.  A controller would also let you better encapsulate some of the other form interactions (such as binding the `ng-change` to a function on your controller).  Otherwise, you could use `ng-init`, but that's a bit frowned upon.